# Why does internet explorer 8 fail to locate jpg files that other browsers can find?

Tags: internet-explorer-8, url

The following URL doesn't display for me in Internet Explorer 8. I even tried compatibility mode and it didn't fix the issue.

http://beat.com.au/sites/default/files/images/_DSC5596.jpg

It appears just fine in Chrome/Safari/Firefox.

I *suspect* it has something to do with the filename starting with `_` but that seems like a fairly big stretch to me.

Is this error repeatable on other people's computers? And why on earth would such a strange thing happen anyway?

Comment: Repeatable here

Comment: Sort of works in IE for me, well the image is found (i.e. no 404), but it isn't displayed. The image could be corrupt in some way maybe?

Comment: very odd...  I'm curious as to what this can be too... I've never seen this with a jpg.  enless it acutally isnt a jpg

Answer (score 7):

I get the same behaviour when I download the image and open it from my desktop in IE8. Works fine in the Windows JPG viewer.

And the reason is that it's a CMYK jpeg. Convert it to RGB and it should work.

This is what happens when you let print designers supply web media.

Comment: this is so freaking weird. I'm still getting the error when I dl the file, and change the filename to remove the "_" so there goes my theory!

Answer (score 0):

The image is in CMYK, see m[y answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17469/ie6-cant-load-a-normal-jpg/17589#17589) for further info.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the image color format. I had this happen with JPEG images whose color format is CMYK. Apparently IE doesn't support JPEG images in CMYK, switch it to RGB and it should display fine.